# Как связать Java проект с html представлением?

Tags: java, html

Хочу сделать сайт с джавой на backend-e но не знаю как

Answer (score 2):

Перед созданием сайта, нужно начать с изучения таких сущностей как основы интернета, HTTP протокол, паттерны проектирования такие как MVC и не только... А на механическом уровне, на чистой Java сайты не пишутся, рассмотри Spring Framework, его устройство и разделение чтобы определённо знать какой функционал вводить. Также для начала советую использовать шаблонизатор Thymeleaf для связки отображения с backend-ом.

Answer (score 2):

самое простое и быстрое это разобраться с начальной формой спрингбута и использовать в pom.xml

```xml
-<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>

-<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

ещё минималистичнее это в @RestController в методе с @ResponseBody выбрасывать в return конкретный прям просто тупо html файл с диска.

правда когда вы доберётесь до запуска этого всего, то поймёте уже как это сделать правильнее :)